# Conversion of Hexadecimal to text

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I need to convert an array of hexadecimal data into text (ASCII) format.
My hexadecimal data is in the group of 8 bits, and I need to remove the spaces and need to get Textual information.

For eg. the hexadecimal data is as follows:
**48454c4c 4f574f52 4c44**

Its equivalent Text is **HELLOWORLD**

I have tried coding, but I could only achieve to convert a string of hex data 48454c4c4f574f524c44 (Without spaces) into text.

Kindly suggest and pls help me to sort it out.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Show us your code.

Comment: 20 is for space. split your hexa decimal number with 20. and convert it to text and bind it

Comment: string hexString = Textbox1.Text;
var bytes = new byte [hexString.Length / 2];
for (var i=0; i<bytes.Length; i++)
{
bytes[i]= Convert.ToByte(hexString.Substring (i*2,2),16);
}
textbox2.Text = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(bytes);

Comment: I din't get you mam.

Comment: This is the 3rd or 4rth time you have asked this question i know of in the last couple of days

Comment: I am not getting the solution for the same

Comment: You need to share your code in the question itself and also explain what behavior you noticed in that code. Are you getting any error? Are you getting different output? How different it is from the expected output? Asking the same question again and again won't get you the correct answer. Asking proper question would increase the chances of getting correct answer. Did you go thru the answers suggested in the duplicate questions?

Comment: Note that the [tag:visual-studio] tag description says *"DO NOT use this tag on questions regarding code which merely happened to be written in Visual Studio."* Please [edit] your question to remove it.